# Release app on devices newer than iphone 5

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to release my app only on iphone 5 and newer devices?

iPhone 4s and earlier devices don't have enough memory to run my app. How can I select which devices my app will run on? Can it done via project settings or editing a plist or in itunes connect?